# Background Subtraction for short videos

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, background-subtraction

I was going through this paper:
Adaptive Background Mixture Models for Real-Time Tracking(1999) by Chris Stauffer, W. Eric L. Grimson

Their method is ok for a long video where one can start making blobs after some time when the gaussian mixture models gets stabilized.

But this won't apply for short videos e.g. [http://cvrc.ece.utexas.edu/SDHA2010/videos/human_interaction.zip](http://cvrc.ece.utexas.edu/SDHA2010/Human_Interaction.html)
Here from the first frame itself, some portion is actually part of foreground.

Can anyone point out me some paper(s) where this problem has been handled?

Thanks,
Kaushik

Comment: I had the same problem. What I did was run the video through the algorithm once to initialize the background model, then a second time (retaining the initialized background model) to do the segmentation. For off-line segmentation this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Monocular Video Foreground/Background Segmentation by Tracking Spatial-Color Gaussian Mixture Models](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cohen/segmentation.pdf) looks like a really fast-to-initialize method. I'm not sure it can achieve segmentation on the first frame though.

Answer (score 0):

[Statistical Background Subtraction for a Mobile Observer](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Publication/1796345/statistical-background-subtraction-for-a-mobile-observer) (Section 4) also handles this issue of background not yet confirmed. Facing some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053345/median-variance-in-background-subtraction) in understanding.